# Multiple web in one domain

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to host three react web sites in one domain. But each web is heavy.
I've heard about the subdomain and subdirectories, but is this done in one file? Or does that mean I'll combine them at hosting stage? (npm start 3 times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sub domains and point to specific directories of your website
as api.domain.com points to one directory, dashboard.domain.com points to another directory and redirects to the specific site.
 Or you can make one directory and place your websites in sub directories and can access them as domain.com/site1 , domain.com/site2 respectively.

[How to create a subdomain and point to a certain directory](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-add-sub-domain-and-make-it-point-to-a-certain-directory)

Comment: Welcome. I upvoted, but am not sure if there is enough detail here for the to implement a solution. Can you ass more, like @jliu did? This certainly points in the right direction, though.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are sub domains, eg:

```
site1.yourdomain.com
site2.yourdomain.com
site3.yourdomain.com
```

Each subdomain has a different directory on your web server, or can even point it to another server. You can look into CI/CD to help automate your build and deployment process.

[How to create subdomains](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9776/2237/how-to-create-a-subdomain-for-my-domain)

[CI/CD Example With Docker](https://medium.com/swlh/an-example-ci-process-for-react-apps-with-docker-2247171a218)